# Android, something like on compass click listener

Tags: android, google-maps, compass

I have my map with a 60° tilt, and I need to set it in 60 again after the user touches the compass, because it sets the tilt to 0°

Comment: use an `OnClickListener` attached to your map `View`?

Answer (score 1):

Question is a little but old, but I´ve run into a similar problem. My solution was:

```
ImageView compass = (ImageView)mMapView.findViewWithTag("GoogleMapCompass");
compass.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override public void onClick(final View v)
            {
                // React on compass click
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Would resetting the tilt angle in [OnCameraChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener.html) do the trick?